# How to manage large numbers of interfaces in C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, oop, inheritance, interface

I am facing the following problem in C++ (but Java answer would also be helpful). I am creating a large number of classes which are all somewhat similar and a large number of functions that run analyses on these classes. Let's say the classes are C1, .., Cn and the functions are f1, .., fn. Each function requires that the class it operates on has certain properties, which is a subset of p1, .., pn.

As a concrete example, let's say

C1 is a p1, p2 and a p3.

C2 is a p1 and a p2.

C3 is a p2 and a p3.

C4 is just a p1.

And I have functions

f1 which needs something that is p1, p2, p3

f2 needs something that is p1, p2

f3 needs something that is p2, p3

f4 needs something that is p1

Now I want f1 to be able to use C1, f2 to be able to use C2 and C1, f3 to be able to use C3 and C1 and f4 to be able to use C1, C2, C3.

Basically different functions have different, overlapping but non-hirarchical requirements. I can't think of an inheritance paradigm that solves this problem on a large scale (with more than 4 classes / functions) without something horrible like the below

```
class p1
class p2
class p3

class p1andp2 : p1, p2
class p2andp3 : p2, p3
class p1andp2andp3 : p1, p2, p3

C1:public p1, p2
//some code
C2:public p1, p2, p3
//EXACTLY THE SAME CODE
C3:public p1
//EXACTLY THE SAME CODE
```

Is there any hope to implement this scenario?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think more information would be helpful. What do you mean by "properties"? Are these methods that the classes implement? Are they types? Are they just random properties? In what why do the functions depend on these properties? Are you using the properties to decide which functions to call, or is this just a type safety issue? There are a number of potential answers here like marker interfaces, templates/generics, visitor patterns or double dispatch, or simple enums, but without more information it's hard to say what approach makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the functions use `static_cast<>` to the property types to achieve compile-time validation that parameters are of the needed types.  You don't need `class p1andp2andp3 : p1, p2, p3` or similar (which I assume you meant to derive C1, C2 and C3 from in your question).

```
struct P1 { };
struct P2 { };
struct P3 { };

struct C1 : P1, P2, P3 { };
struct C2 : P2, P3 { };
struct C3 : P1, P3 { };

template <typename P>
void fa(const P& p)
{
    // whichever you need...
    // const P1& p1 = static_cast<const P1&>(p);
    const P2& p2 = static_cast<const P2&>(p);
    const P3& p3 = static_cast<const P3&>(p);
    // use pns as needed...
}

int main()
{
    fa(C2());
}
```

Further - is the capitalisation of "EXACTLY THE SAME CODE" meant to be a protest or request for assistance in factoring that code?  If so, can you show what kind of code repeats...?

Answer (score 0):

Consider reviewing the architecture of the standard template library.  That library solves a similar set of algorithms by decoupling the functions from the classes through the use of templates instead of inheritance.

The STL has many ways to store data.  Instead of having a separate sorting function for each of the data structures, the sorting function takes iterators into the data structure which conform to an expected interface.  In this way, the code complexity is reduced from being polynomial (N data structures)*(M algorithms) to linear (N data structures) + (M algorithms) + (K iterators).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their comments / feedback. I did not know about casting before so that was really helpful for me to learn. "Tony D", after some research it seems to me like dynamic_cast<> would be safer to use than static_cast<> for this purpose ...

I think the best answer for me (after loads more research) is virtual inheritance. I can do the following:

```
class p1
class p2
class p3

class p1andp2 : virtual p1, virtual p2
class p2andp3 : virtual p2, virtual p3
class p1andp2andp3 : virtual p1, virtual p2, virtual p3

C1 : p1, p2, p3, p1andp2, p2andp3, p1andp2andp3

f1(p1andp2andp3 input);
f2(p1andp2 input);
```

...

This strategy has complexity O(xy) with x the number of different signatures required by functions and y with the average number of classes which have that signature. This is not linear, but I don't have to use templates.

If one would have to use templates, then static_assert seems like a helpful keyword: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert